# SwiftUI: Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior (when using `ViewModel` approach)

Tags: xcode, swiftui, mvvm

I've read a number of questions about this error that relates to dismissing sheets, but none dealing with SwiftUI's Map.  The following code generates this error.  Nothing is being updated in the view model.  I'm simply passing a binding to a region into the Map initializer.  Using a local state variable for region works with no error.  I'm running Xcode 14.0.  If I remove the @Published property wrapper then the error goes away.  So I'm confused as to how the view model should notify the view that the region has changed, perhaps due to location updates.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

class MM : ObservableObject {
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
}

struct SimpleMap: View {
    @ObservedObject var mm = MM()
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))

    var body: some View {
        //Error
        Map(coordinateRegion: $mm.region)
        
        //No Error
        //Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `StateObject` instead of `ObservedObject`

Comment: `ObservableObject` object initialised with `@StateObject` and when you pass it to other views, in those views you need to declare it with `@ObservedObject`

Comment: we don't use view model objects in SwiftUI

Comment: `@StateObject` does not change a thing. Essentially, ObservableObjects with Published properties are not allowed to be reference bound since iOS16 and Swift 4. You need to use an `@State` property without ever touching it manually ever again.

Comment: So in iOS 16 using `ObservableObject` with `Published` is no longer correct? So what is the use of `Published` now?

Comment: @MartinMajewski would you be able to provide an official reference to the issue you mentioned, please.

Comment: @JohnH have you solved this issue?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I've switched to using  MKMapView.  Swift UI's Map is just too limited and perhaps only applicable for simple applications

Comment: @Martin Majewski I believe you are right, but I don't understand your proposed solution. Would you mind to write a short answer related to the example code?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I overlooked your questions. My response was more on the sarcastic side. In October of 2022, Xcode had this bad circular reference issue that drove me crazy, too. The only solution was to either use @State and never wrote anything to it manually (sarcastic b/c useless!) or to go with the UIKit-version of MapKit and wrap it into a ViewRepresentable. I went with the latter option. With Xcode 14.2, this supposed bug seems resolved for the most part. Maybe the SwiftUI MapKit version is acceptable to use now?

Comment: There's ai a bit of incorrect information in these comments. In iOS 16 using ObservableObject with Published is still allowed, and necessary if you have to be compatible with older OSs. In iOS 16 you don't use Published if you use the Observable macro. The code above is technically correct, but you could just use a second state var for mm.region instead of putting it in a viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@MainActor` attribute to the ViewModel, and replace `@ObervedObject` with `@StateObject`.

Here's an example of how it could be implemented:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct SimpleMap: View {
    @StateObject var vm = VM()

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $vm.region)
    }
}

extension SimpleMap {
    @MainActor class VM: ObservableObject {
        @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
    }
}
```

The most important thing here is the `@MainActor` attribute.